# Referencing HTML Object in VB.net?

Tags: html, vb.net

I want to load `tools.dathost.net` (CS:GO cross hair generator) using the `System.Windows.Forms.Webbrowser` class. And have a textbox in my form that is always equal to the `crosshair_config_console` object on the page. 
Is there a built in function to do this? Or am I going to have to try and write my own?

Comment: Plus one, just because I've been playing CS again in the last few weeks after a couple years away from the game, and noticed last night I needed to tweak the crosshair.

Comment: Glad I could be of some service, on another note, if you are playing cs now, I reccomend this: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=365126929 to tweak your viewmodel